# How Linux update '/proc/loadavg' periodically?

Tags: linux, load

In Linux source code, I found `get_avenrun()` will be [called](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/345671ea0f9258f410eb057b9ced9cefbbe5dc78/fs/proc/loadavg.c#L17) in `fs/proc/loadavg.c` to get load averages over the last 1, 5, and 15 min. But in `get_avenrun()` [definition](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/345671ea0f9258f410eb057b9ced9cefbbe5dc78/kernel/sched/loadavg.c#L73), it just assigned `avenrun[i]` to its first parameter.  It means calling this function periodically can not update `/proc/loadavg`.

In `kernal/sched/loadavg.c` there are only 2 places where global `unsigned long avenrun[3];` will be changed,

- `static void calc_global_nohz(void)`
- `void calc_global_load(unsigned long ticks)`

I just wonder which internal process/thread calls these 2 functions periodically(or are there other ways to update `avenrun[3]` periodically), and What's the difference between `calc_global_nohz()` and `calc_global_load()`.